# how to get video from iphone Library

Tags: iphone

i want to pick a Video from Library.  here is my code.

```
picker1 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker1.delegate = self;
NSArray *mediaTypesAllowed = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];

picker1.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
picker1.mediaTypes = mediaTypesAllowed;
[self presentModalViewController:picker1 animated:YES];
```

}

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
if ([picker isEqual:picker1])
{
    NSString *mediaType = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    if([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]){
        NSLog(@"%@",info);
    }
}
```

problem is when i select video from Library, simulator getting hanged. Even delegate method didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not calling

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer [Accessing_the_iOS_5_iPhone_Camera_and_Photo_Library](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Accessing_the_iOS_5_iPhone_Camera_and_Photo_Library) link and check your code.

Comment: your code looks fine... try to remove `NSLog` line or comment it.. and also write picker1 instead of picker when you dismiss it..

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
myImagePickerController.mediaTypes =
[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
```

or refer this
[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType](http://zcentric.com/2008/08/28/using-a-uiimagepickercontroller/%22refer%20this%22)
Hope this helps u